# What can I do with new lines in file name?

Tags: bash, ls

If a file has new line symbol in it, and I use find or ls, it shows as "?" symbol in a file name. But when I use | to do anything more with it, it splits the string and messes up everything. How do I deal with it?

Comment: Could you pelase give a more specific example for what you do? I fail to see 1. how you get a newline character into a filename and second what that should cause as effect later.

Comment: you make a file with new line in it like this:
touch "asdasd{press enter here}asdasd"
and I need to change permisions to the files afterwards

Comment: What can you do with newlines in a filename? You can hate them.

Comment: Already has answers in `unix.SE`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead https://superuser.com/questions/129519/which-file-systems-support-newlines-in-file-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pipe the results of ls at all. It is, as you see, unpredictable. Use  `find` instead:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -exec command {} \;
```

`{}` represents the file name.

Alternatively you can also use glob expressions. The results of a glob expression are not subject of word splitting, meaning it is safe if they contain newlines or spaces:

```
for file in ./* ; do
    command "$file"
done
```

The results of that commands can then be used in another pipe.

Comment: @msw Thank you! I was actively searching for that link! :)

Comment: Thanks!  
but parsing from find doesn't help either. Using exec is the way to go here.

Comment: In comments you told that you'll change permissions, in that case `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec chmod PERM {} \;` would do the job. Also find has the option `-print0` which separates output by `0` bytes. This can be used to reliably parsing file names with potential spaces/newlines in them. I don't see where `exec` should help here.

Comment: Oh, probably I misread your comment. If you mean the `exec` option of `find` then yes. I thought you meant bash's exec. As I told `-print0` can be used to produce output separated by null bytes.